# GIT is ignoring .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

So i'm in a bit of a trouble here.

This is my .gitignore:

```
 www/*
!www/wp-content/themes/bridge-child*
*.DS_Store
```

So what it should do is to ignore all the files inside www and .ds_store except the items inside bridge-child.

Here is my folder tree:

```
MASTER (Where the .git ignore is)
|
sub - main (My two folders)
```

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong here? 
Kind regards

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format): Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. P.S. `www/*`; `!www/wp-content`; `www/wp-content/*`; `!www/wp-content/themes`; `www/wp-content/themes/*`; `!www/wp-content/themes/bridge-child*`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've told us what you want, but you haven't explained how it isn't working. Is something not being ignored that you expect to be ignored? Is something that you expect not to be ignored being ignored? We can't tell you what's wrong if we don't know what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this solution is the best or effective. But it works.

```
www/*
!www/wp-content

www/wp-content/*
!www/wp-content/themes/

www/wp-content/themes/*
!www/wp-content/themes/bridge-child
```